# How to add link in tweet

Tags: cakephp, twitter

I am using cakephp twitter plugin. What i want to do, I need add page reference URL in tweet.

Currently i add tweet it showing link as text like this

```
In which year of First World War Germany declared war on Russia and France?<a href="xyz.com">click here</a>
```

But I need link on `click here` in tweet.

How can i do that

my tweet code like this

```
public function updateStatus($status, $options = array()) {
        if ($status != null || $status != '') {
            $body = Set::merge(array(
                'status' => $status
                ), $options);

            return json_decode($this->apiRequest('post', $this->endPoint('statuses/update'), $body), true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you need the references link HTML code is replaced by the URL itself, since Twitter only accepts plain text, right?

Try this inside `updateStatus`:

```
$status = preg_replace('#<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)</a>#', '\\2', $status);
```